# Keeping bookmarklet from generating multiple event listeners

Tags: javascript, iframe, bookmarklet

I currently am working on a bookmarklet that opens an iframe, and sets up a communication of postMessage back and forth. That all works fine.
However, seemingly because the bookmarklet is being loaded as an anonymous function, the listeners are multiplying if I run the bookmarklet more than once on a page.

Is there some sort of way to keep track of these addEventListeners so that they don't double-up?

Do I need to define the rp_receive_message outside of the anonymous function?

Here's an example of the code:

```
var rp_receive_message = function (e) {
    var response = e.data;
    console.log("got message with "+ response);
  };

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('message', rp_receive_message, false);
} else {
  window.attachEvent('onmessage', rp_receive_message);
}

var s1 = window.document.createElement('iframe');

s1.setAttribute('src', 'http://mydomain.com/iframe.html');
s1.setAttribute('id', 'testiframe');
s1.setAttribute('width', '700');
s1.setAttribute('height', '550');
s1.setAttribute('frameBorder', '0');
s1.setAttribute('onload', 'this.contentWindow.postMessage(window.location.href, "http://mydomain.com/iframe.html");');


document.getElementById('container').appendChild(s1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this will solve the problem:

```
window.onmessage = rp_receive_message;
```

As you suggest, the code below might be enough by itself. I don't know if addEventListener and attachEvent will add the same function multiple times, but I wouldn't at all be surprised if they will. I suggest  just testing it.

```
window.rp_receive_message = function(){...}
```

If you dislike either solution, you've got to set up a global variable, which hardly seems any different or greatly superior to above. The global can be a simple boolean to check if the event has been attached, or it can be a list of attached events that you update yourself. AFAIK, and I'm pretty sure, there is no native JS solution to get a list of event listeners have been attached to a particular event. Libraries such as jQuery maintain lists and let you read them; and possibly have other techniques that are elegant solutions to your general problem.

Comment: Simple, but workable solution! It appears that multiple runs effectively overwrite window.onmessage with the new rp_receive_message instead of making a new listener to a new anonymous function's rp_receive_message each time. I'll have to try it out in various environments. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know why calling window.postMessage on a window.onmessage in IE8 does not seem to pass the event? In my above example (using window.onmessage), e is undefined, and e.data of course does not exist, but the function is fired.

Comment: `
window.onmessage = function(e){ alert(e.data)};
window.postMessage('hey','https://www.google.com');
`
Results in 'SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'data': object is null or undefined' on IE9 in IE8 mode. The postMessage calls the function, but 'e' is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Unsure. What I've seen online suggests it should work. Maybe try adding this `e = e || window.event;`.